# Upgraded to python3.8 and broke it

Tags: python, path, dependencies

I upgraded to python3.8.2 and I started having issues. So I uninstalled pip. Now I try to install it again.

```
python3 -m pip install --user --upgrade pip
-bash: /usr/bin/python3.8: No such file or directory
```

When I try and install pip I get this.
`ImportError: cannot import name 'sysconfig' from 'distutils' (/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/__init__.py)`

I don't understand what happened.
I tried removing python3.8

```
sudo apt remove python3.8  
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'python3.8' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

But then I get the version

```py
-bash: /usr/bin/python3.8: No such file or directory
```

Help.

Comment: How did you upgrade python3.8?

Comment: apt-get install python3.8

Comment: from the 2nd result block, it says python3.8 isn't installed, so what happens if you do a ```sudo apt install python3.8```?

Comment: it installed but the problem persists. Same thing.

Comment: does python3.8 exist in /usr/bin?   what happens if you type ```python3.8 -V```?

Comment: python3.8 -V
Python 3.8.3

Comment: Yes it is. ```ls| grep python
dh_python2
dh_python3
python
python2
python2.7
python3
python3-config
python3.5
python3.5-config
python3.5m
python3.5m-config
python3.8
python3m
python3m-config
x86_64-linux-gnu-python3-config
x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.5-config
x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.5m-config
x86_64-linux-gnu-python3m-config
```

Comment: I'm beginning to think that 1) this should be moved to unix.so, and 2) your python 3.8 is installed somewhere else and the one in /usr/bin was manually installed somehow (or python3.8 is a symlink elsewhere?